# Ext JS - adding listeners at run-time

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, extjs5

I'd like to be able to add listeners to active elements as specified in a setup file. The setup file might be something like this:

```
<listeners>
    <listener>
        <field>id</field>
        <match>button-*</match>
        <using>reg-exp</using>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>button-yes</exclude>
            <exclude>button-no</exclude>
            <exclude>button-cancel</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <event>click</event>
        <action>onButtonClick</action>
    </listener>
    <listener>...</listener>
</listeners>
```

Which means any element with an id matching `button-*`, except `button-yes`, `-no` and `-cancel`, will call `onButtonClick` when a `click` event is triggered.

It doesn't necessarily have to be a built-in event, can be custom, like `fileSystemException`, or `userTimedOut`. So an event can be fired somewhere in the code and all the elements listening to it will have the respective actions invoked.

Ideally, would like to load the setup file very early before any elements are created, and be able to have a listener added even to an element created at runtime. So for example a new element with ID `button-reject`, created on the fly, which fulfills the criteria, will get the listener. So I guess it has to extend a low level creation method?

Has anything like this been done in ExtJS? Say by extending one or more base classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can load this file into a JSON Object or an ExtJS [HashMap](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.HashMap), then you can globally listen for a component's [afterrender](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-event-afterrender) event to inspect your HashMap or JSON Object for a match and apply the corresponding listener.

Something like that may work, but that does mean every component will have to check to see if there is a listener that should be applied which will probably have a huge performance overhead.

Comment: Can you suggest a reference on how to add a global listener for `afterrender`? I tried `Ext.on("afterrender", function(data) {
 for (key in data)
  console.log("*** after-render " + key + "\t" + data[key]);
});` before the application is defined, but it's not being called.

Comment: You can add it to the init or constructor of a main controller:  `Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
     init: function() {
         this.listen({
             component: {
                 '*': {
                    afterrender: this.someMethod
                 }
             }
         });
     },
     ...
 });`

Comment: Their [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-listen) may be more clear.

Comment: For information
if you want to add listener in the view, then you can do following
```constructor: function(cfg) {
this.callParent(arguments);
this.on('afterrender', this.someFunction, this);
}```